# pyinstaller warnings stopped but executable file does not work

Tags: pyinstaller, executable, libs

Why does the executable not work? I followed the top instructions of an older, similar, problem and the warnings (missing dlls) stopped, the executable was created in the dist folder but it does not work on double click. Here is a copy of the screen, having typed the two lines below:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAVE THESE>PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32\downlevel;
C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAVE THESE>pyinstaller -w -F WFinder_v2db.py  
343 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
359 INFO: Python: 3.7.2
359 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
359 INFO: wrote C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAVE THESE\WFinder_v2db.spec
374 INFO: UPX is not available.
390 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\SAVE THESE', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\SAVE THESE']
390 INFO: checking Analysis
390 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
390 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
406 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
421 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
14258 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
14258 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
16813 INFO: Caching module hooks...
16828 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAVE THESE\WFinder_v2db.py
18375 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
25757 INFO: Loading module hooks...
25757 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
25773 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
26112 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lxml.etree.py"...
26112 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
26112 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
26442 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
27245 INFO: checking Tree
27245 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
27245 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
27762 INFO: checking Tree
27762 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
27762 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
27963 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
27963 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
27963 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
27994 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
30947 INFO: Looking for eggs
30947 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
30949 INFO: Found binding redirects:[]  
30967 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAVE THESE\build\WFinder_v2db\warn-WFinder_v2db.txt
31169 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAVE THESE\build\WFinder_v2db\xref-WFinder_v2db.html
31360 INFO: checking PYZ
31360 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
31362 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAVE THESE\build\WFinder_v2db\PYZ-00.pyz
33153 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAVE THESE\build\WFinder_v2db\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
33209 INFO: checking PKG
33209 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
33209 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
48156 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
48312 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\runw.exe
48312 INFO: checking EXE
48312 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
48312 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
48312 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAVE THESE\dist\WFinder_v2db.exe
49562 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I had forgotten the closing line `root.mainloop()` in the GUI (tkinter) code. Now the executable works. A missing line of code did give me the trouble.